# In bash configure shortcut ctrl+c for copy if text is selected and for SIGINT if no text is selected

Tags: bash, unix

For `/bin/bash` I want to configure this behavior when pressing ctrl+c:

1. If no text is selected in the terminal SIGINT is sent (this is the standard behavior and interrupts the running process and gives you a new prompt to write your next command)
2. If text is selected in the terminal the selected text is copied to the clipboard and no SIGINT is sent (this is not the standard behavior; it can be configured (`Preferences -> Shortcuts -> Copy`) but not without loosing behavior #1)

This exact behavior can be configured in PHPStorm easily by selecting `/bin/bash` in `Tools -> Terminal` and chosing the option `Copy to clipboard on selection` so I think it should be possible somehow.

#### Note

I already read the very informative accepted answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245421/ctrlc-copy-or-interrupt).

Comment: You may be able to interface with whatever your clipboard manager is and determine if there is an active selection (select-copy) pending and then tell the clipboard manager to copy the selection from the select-copy buffer to the copy-buffer. But all would depend on what clipboard manager is running... Not very useful unless you are going to write a giant `case` statement to test all possible clipboard managers -- from a portability standpoint `:)`

Comment: I tried to implement the desired behavior on my own with the bind program but I absolutely did not suceed :) If you have an implementation I would be interested of course :) One clipboard manager would be enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ctrl/C behavior is provided by the terminal emulator, and not by bash. The process that runs inside the window (bash, or whatever command is initiated) does not "see" the clipboard. It is up to the terminal emulator to decide what characters to send on when the user clip on a key.

If the terminal emulator does not have this feature, you are out of luck. Consider opening enhancement request for your favorite terminal emulator (gnome-terminal, ...).